# htaccess not working in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

Hi I have an admin folder that has pretty much the same custom system as my root folder so I need `htaccess` to make the URL's look nice so in root I have:
`example.com/home` and admin should be `example.com/admin/home`.
My root's `htaccess` is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works fine but no matter what I do when I have a copy of this in the admin folder it does not work. I have tried `RewriteBase` I have tried doing the admin folder from the root `htaccess` but anything I try always makes the pages 404 or 500 error.

Admin htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have set properly admin folder's [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive? You can set that in your site's configuration file.

Comment: I have added `AllowOverride All` and it has changed it to an internal 500 error.

Comment: [AllowOverride directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) CANNOT be placed in htaccess -- only in directory context.

Comment: That will explain why. I only have access to htaccess but I am guessing we do have AllowOverride due to the fact that the root folder htaccess works.

Comment: @Sam_Benne Yep, that should be it (I mean, Allow Override should be fine as it is). Try without rewrite base and leading slash e.g. `index.php` and not `/index.php`. If you still having 500 error -- then check Apache error log for exact description (you should have access to it even on shared hosting).

Comment: @LazyOne I just get 404 error. Trying this locally it works, with slight difference as it's local and the only difference is ./index but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @@Sam_Benne Well .. if it works locally (dev PC) and does not work remotely then: 1) rules are fine .. but need tweaking for different environment/setup; 2) You need to debug it on remote (you need edit server config, which you do not have access to). Without knowing for sure what is going wrong it's very difficult to suggest anything. If you can -- try moving rules from htaccess in `/admin/` folder into main htaccess in root folder -- this definitely makes life easier (at least from debugging POV).